# shlwapi.h compile errors in imported project

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I am trying to import a C++ MFC project from Visual Studio 2008 into VS 2019 community edition.  The project originally came from outside my company long ago (like maybe twenty years).  I am getting hundreds of compiler errors from an MFC include file named shlwapi.h because many symbols in it are multiply defined.  Has anyone else seen this, and what can I do about it?

Edit:  Here are some samples of the errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\Shlwapi.h(287,16): error C2084: function 'HRESULT SHLocalStrDupW(PCWSTR,PWSTR *)' already has a body
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\Shlwapi.h(287): message : see previous definition of 'SHLocalStrDupW'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\Shlwapi.h(293,16): error C2084: function 'HRESULT SHLocalStrDupA(PCSTR,PSTR *)' already has a body
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\Shlwapi.h(293): message : see previous definition of 'SHLocalStrDupA'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.19041.0\um\Shlwapi.h(916,5): error C2365: 'URL_SCHEME_INVALID': redefinition; previous definition was 'enumerator'
```

When I click on the first line, I am taken to this code:

```
// make the above helper function a bit easier to use in the HRESULT world
inline HRESULT SHLocalStrDupW(_In_ PCWSTR psz, _Outptr_result_maybenull_ PWSTR *ppsz)
{
    *ppsz = StrDupW(psz);
    return *ppsz ? S_OK : E_OUTOFMEMORY;
}
```

When I click on the second line, the one that says "see previous definition", I am taken to the same place.  It's like the include guard at the top of the file isn't working.

Comment: *shlwapi* isn't MFC. It's the [Shell Lightweight Utility API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shlwapi), part of the Windows SDK. Regardless, if you need help, post at least *some* information.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I don't know what more information I can provide.  I guess the first question becomes:  has anyone successfully used the Shell Lightweight Utility API in a Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition project?  Also, what tag would you suggest I use instead of MFC?

Comment: You get errors. That would be valuable information. We don't even know whether they are compiler or linker errors, or something else altogether. Rest assured, though, tens and hundreds of thousands of developers have used the SHLWAPI in VS 2019.

Comment: I told you that they are multiply defined symbols.

Comment: You can use the [/showIncludes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/showincludes-list-include-files) compiler option to find out, where this header gets included from. This might help you narrow in the root issue.

Comment: Great!  I wasn't aware of that option.  Years ago, I wrote a program that would take a precompiler output file (/I option, if I remember right) and strip out everything that wasn't a #include file or an end of file marker.  It was quite helpful.  Unfortunately, I left it behind when I changed jobs.